# How can I delete rows by grouping by ID and specific column arithmetic in R?

Tags: r

I have a large dataset that looks something like this...

```
Pos  GOIcp  HKGcp        ID
A2   5.49   24.92   1_pDLS_Pdyn
A3   26.80  25.71   1_pDLS_Pdyn
A5   26.83  25.44   16_pDLS_Pdyn
A6   27.03  25.53   16_pDLS_Pdyn
A7   26.78  25.28   16_pDLS_Pdyn
A9   26.91  25.97   6_pDMS_Pdyn
A10  26.65  25.98   6_pDMS_Pdyn
A11  26.15  25.60   6_pDMS_Pdyn
A13  22.93  25.50   1_pDLS_Penk
A14  22.79  25.42   1_pDLS_Penk
A15  22.76  25.29   1_pDLS_Penk
A17  21.94  24.54   16_pDLS_Penk
A18  21.67  24.46   16_pDLS_Penk
A19  22.54  25.21   16_pDLS_Penk
A22  23.15  25.17   6_pDMS_Penk
A23  22.92  25.02   6_pDMS_Penk
C1   26.25  25.58   2_pDLS_Pdyn
C2   26.95  25.99   2_pDLS_Pdyn
C3   26.82  26.06   2_pDLS_Pdyn
C5   27.22  25.55   17_pDLS_Pdyn
C6   29.25  25.61   17_pDLS_Pdyn
C7   27.27  25.71   17_pDLS_Pdyn
```

To start, I want to group the function by the ID column. Then, looking at the ID's I want to remove any rows in which the difference between the rows in the 2nd column for each ID is greater than 1.5 for that ID. However, if say, all of the rows for that ID have a difference greater than 1.5, then keep the rows.

For a better explanation, row 1 and 2 would be kept because the it's only 2 rows and the points are far apart. But, the last 3 rows there is one data point for that ID that is greater than a difference of 1.5 from the other 2 rows. So, the 29.25 row should get deleted from the dataframe.

I hope this makes sense. And any help would be great!

I have tried doing some "for loops" to do this but aside from manually deleting the rows, I'm not sure how to go about this.

Edit: The output would look like this...

```
    Pos  GOIcp  HKGcp        ID
    A2   5.49   24.92   1_pDLS_Pdyn
    A3   26.80  25.71   1_pDLS_Pdyn
    A5   26.83  25.44   16_pDLS_Pdyn
    A6   27.03  25.53   16_pDLS_Pdyn
    A7   26.78  25.28   16_pDLS_Pdyn
    A9   26.91  25.97   6_pDMS_Pdyn
    A10  26.65  25.98   6_pDMS_Pdyn
    A11  26.15  25.60   6_pDMS_Pdyn
    A13  22.93  25.50   1_pDLS_Penk
    A14  22.79  25.42   1_pDLS_Penk
    A15  22.76  25.29   1_pDLS_Penk
    A17  21.94  24.54   16_pDLS_Penk
    A18  21.67  24.46   16_pDLS_Penk
    A19  22.54  25.21   16_pDLS_Penk
    A22  23.15  25.17   6_pDMS_Penk
    A23  22.92  25.02   6_pDMS_Penk
    C1   26.25  25.58   2_pDLS_Pdyn
    C2   26.95  25.99   2_pDLS_Pdyn
    C3   26.82  26.06   2_pDLS_Pdyn
    C5   27.22  25.55   17_pDLS_Pdyn
    C7   27.27  25.71   17_pDLS_Pdyn
```

I wish it were as simple as deleting the C6 row (regarding the Pos column) but take into consideration that this is a large dataframe and I only presented a sample.

Edit: Here is a recreation of my above sample data...

```
df1 <- structure(list(Pos = c("A2", "A3", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A9", "A10", "A11", "A13", "A14", "A15", "A17", "A18", "A19", "A22", "A23", 
"C1", "C2", "C3", "C5", "C6", "C7"), GOIcp = c(5.49, 26.8, 26.83,                                                                       27.03, 26.78, 26.91, 26.65, 26.15, 22.93, 22.79, 22.76, 21.94, 
21.67, 22.54, 23.15, 22.92, 26.25, 26.95, 26.82, 27.22, 29.25, 
27.27), HKGcp = c(24.92, 25.71, 25.44, 25.53, 25.28, 25.97, 25.98, 
25.6, 25.5, 25.42, 25.29, 24.54, 24.46, 25.21, 25.17, 25.02, 
25.58, 25.99, 26.06, 25.55, 25.61, 25.71), ID = c("1_pDLS_Pdyn", 
"1_pDLS_Pdyn", "16_pDLS_Pdyn", "16_pDLS_Pdyn", "16_pDLS_Pdyn", 
"6_pDMS_Pdyn", "6_pDMS_Pdyn", "6_pDMS_Pdyn", "1_pDLS_Penk", "1_pDLS_Penk", "1_pDLS_Penk", "16_pDLS_Penk", "16_pDLS_Penk", "16_pDLS_Penk","6_pDMS_Penk", "6_pDMS_Penk", "2_pDLS_Pdyn", "2_pDLS_Pdyn", "2_pDLS_Pdyn", "17_pDLS_Pdyn", "17_pDLS_Pdyn", "17_pDLS_Pdyn")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-22L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have not tested on your data as you did not provide the data as code (please provide dput(), but something like this may help.

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
       arrange(GOIcp) %>%
       filter(all(dif(GOIcp)>1.5[-1])|(dif(GOIcp)<=1.5|lag(dif(GOIcp)<=1.5) %>%
       ungroup()
```

Comment: I added an "edit" to recreate my sample data set

Comment: unfortunately that code keeps giving me an error

Comment: maybe it is because the ")" is not correct? What would be the correct ")"